# Removing "Show In" menu items in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, and would like to remove some of the items displayed in the "Show In" context menu. The items are placed in this menu by various plug-ins, and I would prefer to not have them there.

Adding a new entry to this menu is well documented: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_my_view_appear_in_the_Show_In_menu%3F

However, removing an existing entry seems problematic, since Views are listed in the "Show In" menu by virtue of them implementing the IShowInTarget interface. The resulting menu items do not have unique IDs that could be used to disable them via an Activity.

It seems to me like the only way to avoid listing a View defined by an existing plug-in in the "Show In" menu is to extend the plug-in class implementing this View.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the 'Show In' menu is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowInMenu`.

This gets contributions from a number of places but I don't see anything that could be used to filter them.

'Extending the plug-in class implementing the view' is not really possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was afraid that this is the case. It looks like my only option is to fork the plug-ins (with all the problems that entails) and modify them so that they don't register any "Show in" menu entries.